# WPF User Control within WinForm Application does not display correctly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I am working to create a Ribbon-style menu that will replace the current UI for already existing Windows Forms Application. After looking at other extensions for Ribbon UI support, I found better options with the WPF libraries.

However, I learned that I had to use a WPF User Control to sort of "import" my created ribbon into the Windows Form Application.

But my problem is that when i build my Windows Form Application, the ribbon that i created on the WPF User Control file looks nothing like the one that is built on the main application. There are components missing and the RibbonGroup titles are incorrectly spaced from each other. The backgrounds of each also do not match.

Is there anything i can try to make sure that the Ribbon i created in the WPF UC will look the same when i build the main application (WinForm) that contains the elementhost (which holds the WPF UC)?

I am quite inexperienced with C# so please try not to leave any details out.

Thanks in advance.